# Expect - Interrupt program - Ctrl+C

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting, tcl, expect

I am running the following script to start a capture on a remote server and download the file afterwards. Currently I have to pause it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and manually exit.

How can I replace the interact and define a trigger to kill the tcpdump or catch the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and pass it inside the remote server?

```bash
spawn ssh "$user_ssh\@$ssh_server"

expect {
        "*password"     { send "$pass\n";   exp_continue}
        "root\@*"       { }
        timeout  { puts "time out expecting password or bash"; exit 1 }
    }

send "sudo tcpdump -i $intf -s0 -w $file -v\n";
interact

spawn scp "$user_ssh\@$ssh_server:$file" .

expect "password:"
send "$pass_ssh\n";
expect "100\%"
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To **send** a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, do:

```
send \x03
```

To **handle** an incoming <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, do:

```
trap {your handler script here} SIGINT
```

You *might* want to make the handler script (which can be a multi-line thing) send the signal on to the inner process…

```
trap {
    send \x03
    send_user "You pressed Ctrl+C\n"
} SIGINT
```

But take care! When the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a text-mode program (in most GUIs, it's a copy action) they are usually expecting it to go away pretty soon, so you should take care to ensure that you don't spend too long after the signal arrives cleaning everything up.

Comment: Is it possible to apply this trap condition only to a particular part?
For instance... In the example this is only useful in the "send "sudo tcpdump -i $intf -s0 -w $file -v\n";" line.